# tcl can't find wsl.exe when executing cmd /c wsl.exe --cd some/path/to/destination

Tags: tcl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My execution call looks like this:
`exec c:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c c:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe --cd $drive_letter/Projects/$project/gs/$unit/netlist >>TestWSL.txt`

And I keep getting the following message when executing:

[Info: Synthese started

Info: Garbage collection in process

Info: Garbage collection successful: The temp directory has been deleted>Info: Now generating temporary data workfiles from imported files open_files.tcl and add_files.tcl

Info: Fetching files open_files.tcl and add_files.tcl for further processing.

Info: Library preprocessing steps initiated.

Der Befehl "c:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04rV1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the native name of files that you pass through `cmd` like that. Try this:

```
set wsl [file nativename c:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe]
set netlist [file nativename $drive_letter/Projects/$project/gs/$unit/netlist]
exec c:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c $wsl --cd $netlist >>TestWSL.txt
```

You *probably* don't need to pass through `cmd` as you are calling an executable, but if you do you must use native names (which just flips the `/` to `\` on Windows; other platforms may do other things).

Comment: I could have done that in one long line... but it's much easier to read when split into three with some helper variables.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and now the paths are correct but wsl.exe still can't be found when running it with cmd from tcl and when running wsl.exe directly .

Comment: It's path is probably different to what you expect then. Sometimes you've just got to "put the correct values in".

Comment: (I don't have wsl installed on this machine, so I can't really test.)

Comment: I've got it to find wsl now but it can't execute it because tcl might execute a cmd that doesn't have the functions of the 64 bit version.